# While loop not returning entire class

Tags: java

I have two while loops, one inner and one outer. The intent of my inner one is to only re-rerun a specific aspect of my code should the user choose to and then close said function after they opt out, and the intent for the outer while loop is to re-run the entire function should the user choose to and then close after they opt out. I am doing this for reusability sake.

> However, I am running into 3 issues.

1. When the program starts, it doesn't allow the first input value to be entered (`Movie name in Main class - String name`) only the other values that follows, but when it re-reruns, then it allows for the first value to be entered.
2. In the case where I select option 2, it doesn't allow me to input the full name in the main class (`String fullName`).
3. In the case where I create 2 movies, a new object isn't created for the second movie, it just overwrites the existing one.

*For my third issue, I'm guessing that in order to create a new obj for each movie created, a loop should be created? I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

I have no idea why I am facing the 1st and 2nd problems but I am guessing it has something to do with the inner and outer while loops.*

I'll try to show my entire code as condense as I can but it may still be lengthy since I am addressing multiple issues, I do apologize in advance.
I have 2 classes

*Movie class*

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Movie {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] genre;
    private String[] actors;
    private String[] language;
    private String countryOfOrigin;
    private Map<String, Integer> ratings;

    Movie() {
    }

    //Constructor
    public Movie(int id, String name, String description, String[] genre, String[] actors, String[] language, String countryOfOrigin, Map<String, Integer> ratings) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.actors = actors;
        this.language = language;
        this.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
//setters
    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setGenre(String[] genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setActors(String[] actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public void setRatings(Map<String, Integer> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    //getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String[] getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nMovie Id: " + id + " \nMovie Name: " + name + "\nMovie Description: " + description + "\nMovie Genre(s): " + Arrays.toString(genre) + "\nMovie Actor(s): " + Arrays.toString(actors) + "\nMovie Language(s): " + Arrays.toString(language) + "\nCountry of Origin: " + countryOfOrigin + "\nRatings: " + ratings +"";
    }

}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main{
   // --- Private global scanner initialization --- //
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int choice;
        final int MAX = 999999999;
        boolean loopAgain = true;
        HashMap<String, Integer> mapRatings = new HashMap<>();

       while (loopAgain){
           System.out.println("\nMovie Voting App");

           System.out.println("\nChoose one of the follow options below");

           System.out.println("\t1. Create a poll");
           System.out.println("\t2. Vote on a poll");
           choice = input.nextInt();

           if (choice == 1) {
               while (loopAgain){
                   Random rand = new Random();
                   int id = rand.nextInt(MAX);

                   System.out.println("\nCreate Poll");

                   System.out.println("\nMovie Name: ");
                   String name = input.nextLine();

                   System.out.println("Movie Description: ");
                   String description = input.nextLine();

                   // --- Function for printing and storing genres in the movie --- //
                   System.out.println("How many genre(s) is in this movie?: ");
                   int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                   String genre[] = new String[num];

                   System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " genre(s) in the movie: ");
                   for (int i = 0; i < genre.length; i++) {
                       genre[i] = input.nextLine();
                   }

                   // --- Function for printing and storing actors into array --- //
                   System.out.println("How many actor(s) star in this movie?: ");
                   int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                   String actors[] = new String[num1];

                   System.out.println("Enter the " + num1 + " actor(s) starred now");
                   for (int i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
                       actors[i] = input.nextLine();
                   }

                   // --- Function for printing and storing the languages the movie is played in --- //
                   System.out.println("How many language(s) does this movie play in?: ");
                   int num2 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                   String language[] = new String[num2];

                   System.out.println("Enter the " + num2 + " language(s) that this movie plays in: ");
                   for (int i = 0; i < language.length; i++) {
                       language[i] = input.nextLine();
                   }

                   System.out.println("Country of Origin: ");
                   String countryOfOrigin = input.nextLine();

                   System.out.println("Enter movie rating (PG OR NC): ");
                   String rating = input.nextLine();

                   System.out.println("Enter the rating age (13 OR 17): ");
                   Integer ratingId = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                   mapRatings.put(rating, ratingId);

                   Movie movie1 = new Movie(id, name, description, genre, actors, language, countryOfOrigin, mapRatings);

                   System.out.println("Enter another movie (y/n)?: ");
                   String answer = input.nextLine();

                   if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y")) {
                       loopAgain = true;
                   }
                   else {
                       System.out.println(movie1);

                       System.out.println("Return the main menu (y/n? : ");
                       String answer1 = input.nextLine();

                       if (answer1.equals("y") || answer1.equals("Y")) {
                           loopAgain = true;
                       }
                       else {
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

            else{
                System.out.println("Voting Poll");

                //Generating random ID
                Random rand = new Random();
                int id = rand.nextInt(MAX);

                System.out.println("\nEnter your full name:");
                String fullName = input.nextLine();

                //Creating object for class Person
                Person obj = new Person(fullName, id);
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't read all your code but if you have two `while` loops inside each other like this then you should _not_ use the same variable as the condition for both the loops, it's bound to generate trouble. So have one variable for the outer loop and one for the inner loop.

Comment: I've inserted a new variable with the same condition and passed it onto the inner loop however I'm still getting the issue of not being able to enter the first input for movie - which is movie name. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Break up the code in your main class into smaller, testable methods.  You'll probably find the problem yourself that way.

Comment: Update: I was able to fix the problem of it not allowing me to enter the name of the movie (which was the first user input). I was calling the global scanner to chose whether to create a movie or create a user, and when I select the option, for some reason it wasn't storing properly. I'm still not sure, but when I declared a new scanner and used that to store the value for the users choice, only then was it giving me the ability to store the movie name